# What happens if two pass values of "1" are defined in /etc/fstab?

Tags: linux, debian, boot

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/vda1 during installation
UUID=xxxx /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/vdb1 during installation
UUID=yyyy none            swap    sw          0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
UUID=zzzz /data ext4 default 0 1
```

In the last line the pass value is set to 1 even though that is reserved to the root partition.
I accidentially did this on my system and now I can't reach it (ssh). What does the double set of "1" do to the system on boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR : nothing.

Details:

as per `man fstab`

> The sixth field (fs_passno).
>
> This  field  is  used  by  fsck(8) to determine the order in which filesystem checks are done at boot time.
>   (...)
>
> Filesystems within  a drive will be checked sequentially, but filesystems on different drives will be checked at the same time to
>                 utilize parallelism available in the hardware.

This will basically impact way fsck (filesystem consitency check) is done, not the way it is mounted. FS mounting will occur sequentially (first to "appear" in fstab will be first to be mounted).

So, for the question, at fsck time, both filesystem will be check in order.

Comment: You were right, the error was laying in the "default" option that should actually be "defaults"

Comment: actually I didn't see the "can't ssh part", I overlooked the "default__no s__" ...